# Huge data table Column

Tags: ui-design

My last column is hidden but when I use position sticky it scrollable till end of table and show empty space

I want to design an "action column" in a horizontally scrollable table that remains hidden but becomes visible on hover. This action column should adjust its height based on the row height, and it should be positioned to the right of the container. Importantly, I do not want to use the position: sticky property because it causes the table to scroll until the last column, which I want to avoid.

How can you achieve this design effectively in CSS and HTML?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.